# How to generate a pink noise image?

Tags: python, numpy, fft, noise, noise-generator

I am trying to replicate ["Frequency Synthesis of Landscapes"](http://paulbourke.net/fractals/noise/) by P. Bourke in Python. I thought it would be a simple

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fft import fft2, ifft2

whitenoise = np.random.uniform(0,1,(256,256,3))
fouriertransformed = np.fft.fftshift(fft2(whitenoise))
pinktransformed = np.reciprocal(fouriertransformed)
pinknoise = ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(pinktransformed)).real
```

but it seems to be way more complicated. How can I achieve this, and how can I check that the power really falls of by 1/f**2 in the resulting image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that by computing `pinktransformed = np.reciprocal(fouriertransformed)` you compute the reciprocal of the *amplitudes*, but what you actually want is *scaling* these amplitudes by `1/f**2`, so you'd have to replace that line with

```
pinktransformed = fouriertransformed / f**2
```

where `f` is an array that contains the *frequencies* corresponding to each bin of the fourier transform.

Comment: I am not sure I can follow. What do you mean by "array containing the frequencies" in the case of an image?

Comment: Your original image takes a spatial position in the image and translates it to an "energy" which is white noise. You are taking a Fourier transform which means that while the value is still energy, the position in the array corresponds to a spatial "frequency" or a 1/wavelength. These are called wave vectors and correspond to plane waves. You need to divide each position by the magnitude of the wave vector at that position.

Comment: As @MattMiguel just explained: The FT gives you an array of amplitudes for some range of frequencies. Ever entry of the vector you get from the fourier transform is an *amplitude* for some given *frequency*. If this fundamental property is not clear I recommend reading an introduction to the continuous and discrete fourier transform.