# How can I generate a pink noise image with the same frequency distribution as another image in python?

Tags: python, numpy, fft, noise-generator

I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65811248/how-to-generate-a-pink-noise-image?newreg=9f04688f6ed9404baf8b37eaccbea667) post to generate pink noise with a certain frequency distribution using fourier transforms. I need to be able to give it an image to match the frequencies, and dimensions for the size of the output noise. The issue I have is my current code generates sometimes generates horizontal black bars in the noise. I've traced the issue down to the line "pinktransformed = fouriertransformed / f**2" where a divide by zero error occurs given certain images as inputs. This doesn't happen for most input images.

[Here is an example of the black bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgGum.jpg)

I think the problem I'm having is that my value for f is incorrect. Right now I am just using the fourier transform of the image as f, but I don't think that's right. The link above says

> f is an array that contains the frequencies corresponding to each bin of the fourier transform. Your original image takes a spatial position in the image and translates it to an "energy" which is white noise. You are taking a Fourier transform which means that while the value is still energy, the position in the array corresponds to a spatial "frequency" or a 1/wavelength. These are called wave vectors and correspond to plane waves. You need to divide each position by the magnitude of the wave vector at that position.

I think my current code would work if I just created this correct value for f, but I just don't understand what it means to divide each position by the magnitude of the wave vector at that position. What would I have to modify in my code to solve this?

Here is my current function (img is loaded as a PIL Image then converted to a numpy array, dim is a 2-tuple):

```
def generatenoise(img,dim):
     whitenoise = np.random.uniform(0,256,(img.shape[0],img.shape[1],3))
     fouriertransformed = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(whitenoise))
     f = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(img))
     pinktransformed = fouriertransformed / f**2
     pinknoise = np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(pinktransformed)).real
     pinknoise = np.resize(pinknoise, (dim[0],dim[1],3))

return pinknoise
```

Comment: Magnitude is `abs(f)`. Though I would think you need to multiply, not divide.

Comment: Also, you should use Gaussian noise as a start point, and you can skip all the `fftshift` calls (if you follow along, you’ll realize you move data back and fourth needlessly).