# How to generate 2D colored noise

Tags: python, image-processing, signal-processing, noise, noise-generator

I'm unsuccessfully trying to generate a 2D array of pink noise. Can anyone explain me how to do this? Otherwise, is there a python library that allows to generate 2D (or higher dimensionality) colored noise (1/f noise)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers given both here and in a related question ([How to generate a pink noise image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65811248/how-to-generate-a-pink-noise-image?rq=3)) give you most of the picture - but I thought I'd lay out a full step-by-step to show how everything comes together.

Especially as it seems people run into issues understanding the "frequency matrix".

**To convert white noise to pink noise**

1. Generate some white noise: `whitenoise = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (256, 256))`
2. Fourier transform and shift low-frequencies to centre (this makes generating the "frequency matrix" more intuitive): `ft_arr = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(whitenoise))`
3. Generate the "frequency matrix". In the 1-D case this would be an array of the actual frequencies which correspond to the amplitudes given by the transform. In the 2-D case, this is the *distance from the center* of our fftshifted fourier space, as the further out to the edges we go, the greater the frequency captured at that point. This can be generated via `np.meshgrid` and `np.hypot` : 
    
    `_x, _y = np.mgrid[0:ft_arr.shape[0], 0:ft_arr.shape[1]]` 
   `f = np.hypot(_x - ft_arr.shape[0] / 2, _y - ft_arr.shape[1] / 2)` 
    
   We then divide the fourier space by the frequencies. 
   `pink_ft_arr = ft_arr / f`
4. Remove singularities that show up due to having a zero-frequency component. (Probably there's a smarter way to do this, but this gave me the expected output regardless): 
    
    `pink_ft_arr = np.nan_to_num(pink_ft_arr, nan=0, posinf=0, neginf=0)`
5. Convert the fourier space pink noise back into image space: 
    `pinknoise = np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(pink_ft_arr)).real`

You can then plot this using matplotlibs `plt.imshow`, or scale it into some sensible range and write it out as an image.

[White noise, from np.random.uniform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fKIL.png) 
[Pink noise generated by the above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LWG6.png)

Comment: I made a version of your code that creates landscapes in 3D, running on the SageMath server. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70085015/how-to-generate-2d-colored-noise#comment136301600_70088244 Note that I use `1/f**2` rather than `1/f`.

Answer (score 1):

1. generate white noise in 2D, e.g. using `np.random.randn`
2. calculate FFT_2D of it (`numpy.fft.fft2`)
3. multiply result (2D spectrum) by `1/f**2` matrix, calculated in such a way:
   `1/f_along_x * 1/f_along_y`.
   That's how I interpret [this definition of pink noise in N-dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pink_noise#Generalization_to_more_than_one_dimension), but I am not sure I am correct!
   **EDIT**: Cris Luengo version (see the comment below) - `1/sqrt(f_x**2+f_y**2)` - seems better for me, but its for you to decide which definition of 2d pink noise to use.
4. Use IFFT_2D to get pink noise image (numpy.fft.ifft2)

Comment: Almost correct! I think `1/f**2` translates to `1/(f_x**2+f_y**2)` (i.e. `f` is the distance to the origin). Although I'm dubious about the claim on the Wikipedia page, I think pink noise is `1/f = 1/sqrt(f_x**2+f_y**2)`, because `1/f**2` is Brownian nose. I've generated these in different number of dimensions, and it doesn't look right when the power increases with the dimensionality.

Comment: Thanks for info @CrisLuengo. I guess it is all about who defines it and what "looks right" for him/her. I like your version much more than the one from wiki, for me it looks better too :)

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. I understand how this method works, but I have problems trying to implement the two frequency matrix. Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @CrisLuengo It seems that we need to multiply the exponent by the number of dimensions. See the table in [Power-law spectra of pink noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pink_noise#Power-law_spectra)

Comment: @PM2Ring That’s the exact same Wikipedia page linked in the answer. I don’t know how linking to that argues against “I think Wikipedia is wrong”. For one, there is no reason to think the integral of the noise over all angles should decrease at a certain rate with frequency, rather than the value for one given angle. Second, I would expect that, given an 2D image with pink noise, if I take a row or column of it, I get a 1D signal with pink noise, not red (Brownian) noise.

Comment: @PM2Ring “dubious” as in “I have doubts about it”, or not being convinced by it. I’ve looked over that section again, and it has only one reference, a poster from 2022 (truly not a useful reference, and which obviously couldn’t have been there when I left that comment in 2021). I think whoever wrote that poster used pink noise images generated as per the description in Wikipedia! :D

Comment: @Cris In the next comment is a demo running on the SageMath server that makes 3D landscapes. It's based on ckyleda's code, but using `1/f**2`. The results look good to me, and using `1/f` gives *very* spiky landscapes. [Paul Bourke](https://paulbourke.net/fractals/noise/) has examples with exponents of 1.8 & 2.4.

Comment: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNUkFuwyAQvPsV9BSwiOu4jVRFQuoTco8iC9nrgmIDxbiJ8%5FouOK1zMOwsM7OsWT046wMx0%2DBmIkdiXJZ9ahPAyyZkLXSkpqO%2Dg9hVH5yMjexBlEW1xxigFe8VO2SEePNFBGoLL01rhwJ1cupDjXmKZjRyGUPiVekASMWDwlg%5FyH5xTyt64rry6i4srl0X4jcq3QW64oomGgpQoaIW6Wl7JRWmOg%5Ffi4GanQ00x8h%2Ded2etol9UEvVZ3SO1Z02l%5F%5Firf7RLdC%5FG%5FFkm%2DcVRyIhdgoCSXfwdqx7fVmJjGMX4EFE%5Foso0y2j89qTTk08gaXDR3nGCg%2DyR1VvOVF60Q3aJALaRyRvC1q9EyZbFDH8DxR1KY7V43N29MZndiAewuRNEp3iE815bH9bFnt0jonbmjij9ojWrrfhraUdJ7TkZMfWPZ7UzqJuXCalsb31IlJTNEg3FjhUXmqTHvhYjMpeaVAwgNi00l82HOfPQYNTI4O2gu7Q%2DjFyKPkFjyjYSA==&lang=python

Comment: @Cris I've added my own answer, with images showing the difference between `1/f**2` and `1/f`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code derived from the [answer by ckyleda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76605642) which plots the landscape in 3D using matplotlib. I use normal white noise, rather than uniform white noise, and I use the modern NumPy [random](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html#random-sampling-numpy-random) interface.

In my tests, plots using the frequencies from `np.hypot` are way too spiky. Using the squares of those frequencies, as suggested in [Power-law spectra of pink noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pink_noise#Power-law_spectra) from Wikipedia appears to give much nicer results.

```
""" Pink noise surface in matplotlib
    Written by PM 2Ring 2023.10.20
"""

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

def pink_noise(size, rand, roughness):
    white = rand(size=(size, size))
    white_ft = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(white))

    hsize = size / 2
    y, x = np.ogrid[-hsize:hsize, -hsize:hsize]
    freq = (x**2 + y**2) ** (1 / roughness)
    pink_ft = np.divide(white_ft, freq,
      out=np.zeros_like(white_ft), where=freq!=0)

    pink = np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(pink_ft)).real
    lo, hi = np.min(pink), np.max(pink)
    return (pink - lo) / (hi - lo)

def test(size=128, seed=None, roughness=1, scale=1/4):
    rng = np.random.default_rng(seed)
    Z = pink_noise(size, rng.normal, roughness)
    Y, X = np.ogrid[0:size, 0:size]

    #plt.style.use('dark_background')
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"}, figsize=(8, 8), constrained_layout=True)
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, antialiased=False, cmap=cm.terrain)
    ax.set_box_aspect((1, 1, scale))
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()

test(size=128, seed=137, roughness=1, scale=1/4)
```

#### Output

[image: Fractal landscape, roughness=1]

Here's the result for the same `size` and `seed`, but with `roughness=2`, so it uses the square roots of the frequencies used in the previous plot.

[image: Fractal landscape, roughness=2]

---

Here's a [version](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyFVF1v2zYUffevuMuLJE%5FRV5q2C0BgKIZtLwWCdsAegkBgpSuLC0WqJJXY%5FfW9JOVYBQrMgGle8hzer3N9dXUF90I9gdLCItjFDLzDHdDnXyOcQwVfTnD%5FEZpPQh2gqZqboq6K%2DrcA%2DYwIo3OzvStL63j3pJ%5FRDFK%5FFJ2eyq%5Flu6p6f1vVt7srcrPbiWnWxoFapvkE3IKa6bDHAWaKoA0RpFZ8wxwMVz2tejmMCq3N7oK7l1E4BBZuA5CtcL9m2QXTDo5gai6GwfmvHcXg0ovdpAGWZeTfk0b%5FADHCT1lCE05PORzjM%5FpgRP9wHWB3Y%5FS5tR4DfjD4lfDpcb9v4Fc40U8G%2Dz2kNZSbXAI2ZHyOshfPosf0HHoeXsoDDkAvjhHmGxptWymeLrgsp2zRIPPwX1h1zsa%5FfUlfhHw3RizGGkCWFQa5DDypcxhFZE5CBQj58BY%5FRivgDLrFKAgncE20jPJLiRn3u507%2DsSSJPkLFRpOPeNQlwOlxTvHJUjqn%2D34jJBqA53USzQzoItdL%2Dws%2DQmEA6Hg5o%5FiZ0qkx3e%5FC%2DXQPxk01Kbklv3tJvlBH%5F0%2Di7pgze3bjZRYTceIPXtz4yt84Iu1giv2j1m8kDoukdXlmxxmqV07a%5FJBnOa9B3cTn9lnlNg5bdKHhLwbLlSSQ3IQ1rXIjRu99UEuaFuTPHpfEd6604wsMbwXOsmi62niFA5te26e1gioRhOyP7m0ZMxo7Ex08YzxmrB8cbpd5p7KGmHrcKwSpnjTVxnDHpq1ZzS8obF%2DdvRUUMX4Il1L56kvh6985JKxjpKH%2DmlTh0JpM1HjxPBaMEByHe4WJQa63krvf%2Dd5Varv25Ae81N2d1aVpz74QE57T72uiltqpD84Xg4eX9mdp8OGv9p%2D7kKBz570RHFVOdTB7LQk5TGi53FPnbUPvr%5Fx6XufBAngpk8JQeR1CVgW1h8VstmfB5f3fPada52WJFPVIauKqmryy43BbjFWaMXenkviRpx8HxOvicRX3G9itRMpDqNLYqWN%5Fs8rQysP3gglcDb2SqU%5F3pH%2Dxvg8ii6%2DcF%5FYUb%2DkPABbGlOhWUrTUa9jkJ3FGNY8RsbCmm%5Fcs8s2B62kUFGr2e47pZYEXQ==&lang=python) with a few more parameters to twiddle. It runs on the SageMath server, but the code is mostly plain Python. It just uses Sage to get the parameters and to do the interactive 3D rendering (which is actually done in the browser by three.js).

Here are the [camera controls](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/181e04eea8b569dc09048f9dc644310ed6b745a6/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js#L14C2-L14C2)

```
//    Orbit - left mouse / touch: one-finger move
//    Zoom - middle mouse, or mousewheel / touch: two-finger spread or squish
//    Pan - right mouse, or left mouse + ctrl/meta/shiftKey, or arrow keys / touch: two-finger move
```

There's an info menu in the bottom right corner, which can be used to save screenshots, or to save the HTML so you can view the landscape without Sage.

To generate cloudscapes, select the 'Blues_r' colormap, and set the `scale` to something small, eg 1/20 (make the scale negative if you want to view the clouds from below). Increase the `gamma` parameter to 2 or 3 for bluer skies.